# Jamis Commuter 4 conversion to derailleur geared

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-rear, conversion

I'm trying to convert my Jamis Commuter bike with an IGH to a 10 speed derailleur setup.

I've got a bit stuck on the project with the rear derailleur.  Here's what I want to verify.  Looking at the attached picture, there's definitely a hole for a derailleur hanger right?

From my research thus far I just need to find a compatible derailleur hanger.  I assume my best bet (since this model never had a hanger) is to look for other Jamis compatible hangers and see if I can find a match.

[image: https://imgur.com/TeDI1cF]

Comment: There is definitely not a hole for a derailleur hanger.

Comment: Good to know.  Didn't know quite what I was looking at.

Comment: Usually on dropouts that are intended to take a replaceable hanger, there's a distinctive cutout that the hanger fits into, [like this](https://www.paragonmachineworks.com/dr2022-steel-frame-components-for-1-1-8-x-22-mm-round-rear-dropout.html). What you've got is an old-school setup that mostly went out of style in the 80s, where the hanger is an afterthought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any holes designed for a derailleur hanger. You should be able to use this type though. It clamps into the horizontal dropout. I've heard them called claw hangers. Don't know if there's a better name for them.

[image]

Comment: Good thing about this approach is that these are the cheapest hangers available.  The weird custom ones can cost 10x what these simple ones cost.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the tip.  I hadn't come across these yet.